# $T(h_k) $ converges weakly $\implies$ $T^{-1}(h_k)$ also?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $T: L^{2}(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $\|Tf\|_{L^2}= \|f\|_{L^2}$ and $T$ is invertible (that is, $TT^{-1}= I= T^{-1} T$).

Let $\{h_{k} \} \subset L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ with $\langle T(h_k), f\rangle := \int T(h_{k})(x) f(x) dx \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ for all $f\in L^{2}.$

> Question: Can we say $\langle T^{-1}(h_k), f\rangle \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ for all $f\in L^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is an isometry with left and right inverse, we have that $T^{-1}=T^{*}$ and then $\langle T^{-1}h_k,f\rangle=\langle T^{*}h_k,f\rangle=\langle h_k,Tf\rangle=\overline {\langle Tf ,h_k\rangle}\to 0.$